# Generic method with different data types parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method that allows user to pass `source` parameter as `Dictionary<string, string>` Or `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but not sure how can I do that without overloading in C#

```
public string JoinUrlQuery<T>(string url, T source, string keyValuePairSeparator = "&", string keyValueSeparator = "=", bool urlEncode = false)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var count = 0;

    foreach (var (key, value) in source)
    {
        count++;
        builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}", key, keyValueSeparator, urlEncode ? Uri.EscapeDataString(value) : value);
        //for List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        if (count != source.Count)
            builder.Append(keyValuePairSeparator);
        //for Dictionary<string, string>
        if (count != source.Keys.Count)
                builder.Append(keyValuePairSeparator);
    }

    return $"{url}?{builder}";
}
```

Comment: Both implement `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` so why not use that as the parameter type rather than `T`? That would allow you to iterate `source` and access `Count`.

Comment: With a slight rewrite `IEnumerable` would suffice; access to the `Count` cannot be necessary since we're enumerating every element regardless.

Comment: For Dictionary<string, string>i would have if (count != source.Keys.Count), and for List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>  i will have if (count != source.Count)

Comment: @DenisS. No, `Dictionary<string, string>` also has a `Count` property, because it implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.count?view=net-6.0

Comment: Working example using `ICollection`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g4URic

Comment: And here's that same code simplified to use `IEnumerable`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N02hBT

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, one more question: what if source param would be a totally different data types, lets say int or string? Is there a way to create a method with constraint where : (Ignore the method body in that case)

Comment: @DenisS. If you could, then how would you implement a method that could take an `int` or a `string`? You could only use any base members defined on `object` which is the same as an unconstrained generic argument.